# Replacement part for old Schwinn pump

Tags: replacement, pump

Where can i find a replacement for the metal part (at the end of the 24 inch hose) that clamps around the valve stem, for an old Schwinn floor pump (30 years?)?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the [chuck](http://www.lezyne.com/product-dpumps-acc-abs2chuckhp.php). I'd guess if you can't find a suitable replacement on ebay, you'd replace the chuck with another manufacturer's chuck whose hose has the same diameter (or maybe even replace the entire hose with another manufacturer's hose).

Comment: Specifically I dunno - but +1 to you for maintaining and refurmishing rather than simply replacing.

Comment: A couple of years back I purchased a replacement hose assembly for a different pump.  Some are fairly generic.